# Angular.js AJAX CORS IE9 Request

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ajax, internet-explorer

So I have access to server side and client side code. I am making a widget which gets embedded into external websites. The widget is loaded async so that the website loads regardless of the widget load or not (so we don't mess up the website).

I am making an ajax call to one of my API URL and am trying to get this to work in IE9. This URL takes a customer header in the form of 'X-ABCD-TOKEN' for authentication. (The 'X-ABCD-TOKEN' is hard-coded somewhere in the project - probably a config file)

The following is an example of the ajax call (client side):

```
$.ajax({
                url: ApiURL + 'path',
                async: true,
                crossDomain: true,
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: requestBody,
                contentType: 'text/plain',
                beforeSend: function(xhr){xhr.setRequestHeader('X-ABCD-TOKEN', ApiToken);},
```

Server side in a .js file I have set the following:

`res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, DELETE, PUT');
res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Authorization, X-ABCD-TOKEN, X-ABCD-API');`

Everywhere online seems to tell me that IE9 does not support Custom headers, even when you bypass the IE9 CORS issue.

I have tried to look into jpillora/xdomain Library and MoonScript/jQuery-ajaxTransport-XDomainRequest, with no successful implementation.

Any help? I won't be able to provide exact code, as its private project.

NOTE: I have the API URL but API services are handled by someone else.
Also without adding `?callback=?` at the end of the URL I get Access Denied. I presume this is to invoke JSONP.(I added this to bypass the CORS issue) This sends the request with an err { status: 200}. And server side is Access Denied, which i presumed is because the TOKEN is not being passed (as it appears undefined server side)?

Regards.

Comment: do the domains sit on the same root domain? EG ```website1.root.com``` and ```website2.root.com```? If so try setting ```document.domain = root.com``` in the client app making the CORS call.

Comment: The domain variable is a 'const' so it cannot be modified. although I tried overriding this and got a 'Error: The URL is invalid'. Although, the api call will be made by clients from another domain so this may not work externally.